# Is it possible to find the closest point to all points in subquadratic time?

Tags: algorithm, distance

An algorithmic question.

Input:

- A list of data points `X`
- A metric function for data points `dist(x,y)` that takes O(1) time to evaluate and obeys the triangle inequality

Is there an algorithm that can return a vector of data points `Y` such that `Y[i]` is the closest point in `X` to `X[i]` in subquadratic time?

Obviously this is possible in O(n^2), because you could just directly check every point. I'm wondering if it might be possible to leverage the triangle inequality to improve on this. I would also be interested in approximate algorithms with provable bounds (i.e. something like `Y[i]` is no more than (1 + log(n)) times the distance  from `X[i]` as the minimum).

Comment: To clarify: `Y[i]` should be the point closest to `X[i]` that isn't `X[i]` itself. Otherwise `Y = X` will be the perfect solution :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such algorithm. Consider a metric where all but one pair of points is at distance 1. That pair cannot be found without consulting its particular distance oracle entry, which requires Omega(n^2) queries in the worst case.

[Cover trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_tree) can be used to solve the exact neighbors problem. The time bound depends on the so-called *doubling dimension* of the metric.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have any intuition about the case of the Euclidean metric in R^d? I think you could only create the exact situation you describe if n <= d + 2 (because n - 1 of the points would need to be vertices of a simplex), so let's say n >> d.

Comment: @Jordan no relevant experience, sorry